# Why Python code for approximating value of pi not giving me the correct value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, pi

The value of pi can be approximated as

=3+4/(2×3×4)−4/(4×5×6)+4/(6×7×8)−4/(8×9×10)+...

Notice how it alternates the plus and minus signs.

Write a function that receives an integer n and returns the approximated value of pi, with n terms computed in the sum above.

When  =1, it returns  3. When  =2, it returns the result of  3+42×3×4, etc.

It should use a for loop. Below is my code:

```
def approximate_pi(n):
    
    if (n==1):
        approx_pi = 3
    elif(n>1):
        sign = 1
        numb = 2
        approx_pi = 3
        counter = 0
        for counter in range(1, n+1):
            approx_pi = approx_pi + sign*(4/((numb)*(numb+1)*(numb+2)))    
            sign = sign*(-1)
            numb += 2  
            counter +=1
    print(approx_pi)

approximate_pi(2)
```

This gives me 3.145238095238095, which is not the same as the 3.166666667 value I should get when n =2. Why?

Comment: The assignment `counter +=1` serves no purpose.  Remember, `counter` is the loop variable in the `for` loop.  It gets set each time through the loop.

Comment: "which is not the same as the 3.166666667 value I should get when n =2. Why?" In your own words, why should that be the result? Step by step, what calculations do you think the code should perform, in order to get that result? Now, carefully check what the code actually does, step by step. Where does it differ from your expectation? Do you still have a question about why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You are looping one time too many because `range(1,n+1)` will iterate `n` times but you ave already included the fist term (3) so you only need `n-1` additional terms.

Note that you don't need to make an exception for `n==1`, the loop will not iterate at all if the range is empty.

Given this, and with a little algebra, the function could be simplified down to:

```
def approximate_pi(n):
    return 3 - 2 * sum((-1)**i/i/(2*i+1)/(2*i+2) for i in range(1,n))
```

Here, the sign is computed using a math trick which leverages the behaviour of odd/even powers of negative numbers.  -1 raised to an even power is 1, -1 raised to an odd power is -1.  Using this, `(-1)**i` produces the alternating signs for the additional terms.  Since we are using `i` values starting from 1, we will get the reversed signs for each term but this is easily handled by the subtracting the sum from 3 instead of adding.

The numerator (4) is reduced to 2 by dividing it by `i` instead of `(2*i)` and then factored outside of the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many loops. When you call `approximate_pi(2)` you get the result of threee calculations. The first value is set outside of the loop to the value `3`. The next value is `3+4/(2*3*4)` and the third is `3+4/(2*3*4)-4/(4*5*6)`. `range(1, n+1)` should be `range(1, n)`.

And now you don't even need the special case for `n == 1` anymore.

```
def approximate_pi(n):
    sign = 1
    number = 2
    approx_pi = 3
    for _ in range(1, n):
        approx_pi = approx_pi + sign * (4 / (number * (number + 1) * (number + 2)))
        sign *= -1
        nnumber += 2
    return approx_pi


for i in range(1, 5):
    print(approximate_pi(i))
```

This gives you the results:

```
3
3.1666666666666665
3.1333333333333333
3.145238095238095
```

I renamed the `counter` variable to `_` because it's unused now.

---

If you feel that the counter variable should be used for something, then you can calculate the sign from it. ;)

```
def approximate_pi(n):
    number = 2
    approx_pi = 3
    for i in range(1, n):
        approx_pi = approx_pi + ((-1) ** (i+1)) * (4 / ((number) * (number + 1) * (number + 2)))
        number += 2
    return approx_pi
```

Of course you could take a similar approach for `number`. This would give you something like:

```
def approximate_pi(n):
    approx_pi = 3
    for i in range(1, n):
        approx_pi = approx_pi + ((-1) ** (i+1)) * (4 / (i*2)/(i*2+1)/(i*2+2))
    return approx_pi
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not attempt to debug code for others. Questions like this are not suitable for the site, as they do not help to build a searchable Q&A library.

Comment: It was a comment first and then I got carried away.